# Citrix XenApp and Citrix XenDesktop - Written in what programming language?

Tags: citrix

Any idea what language Citrix products are written in? (XenApp, formerly Metaframe and Presentation Server), XenDesktop, etc? I've been wondering this for years.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, C, OCaml, Python.

OCaml and Python are mentioned there: http://caml.inria.fr/pub/ml-archives/caml-list/2009/07/36fee5f2c665901f2dc7d1b647c4eace.en.html.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the previous answer. Also, recent releases use C#. Notice how the NET Framework is a requirement for most of the Citrix installers. The web components are written in a combination of languages and frameworks including Javascript, ASP NET, and C#. The classic management console is written in Java and I think that most of the command line tools are written in C++.